# Static control get text color

Tags: windows, colors, static

On Windows, once a Static control has been painted (it is already shown), how can we retrieve its text color ?

I have tried with GetTextColor(), GetDCPenColor() but they don't work.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`GetSysColor(COLOR_BTNTEXT)` or `GetThemeColor` if you are using Visual Styles. A subclassed control might change the default by handling `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`.

Comment: The Static control has been subclassed and it is using a certain color, and thats the color I am looking for. From WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC SetTextColor() has been used. How to get the color that was used once used ?

Comment: Then you also need to subclass. `CallWindowProc` to let the other guy set the color and then get it with `GetTextColor `...

Comment: GetTextColor() is returning zero, not CLR_INVALID, but it is not correct

Comment: I am afraid that GetPixel() has to be used to find the used text color for the subclassed Static control

Comment: Maybe post the code you have that fails...